# I have a working Angular 4 app. Is there an easy way to extend it to be compatible with Ionic 3 framework?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have recently finished creating a Angular 4 app which is fully deployed and working fine as a single page web application running on top of browsers.

I want to develop mobile apps for this (Android/iOS), but I really want to avoid starting from the scratch. Since I am not familiar with mobile developments, I want to minimize my effort on maintaining them by using Ionic framework.

Since Ionic 3 is built on top of Angular 4, I do see a lot of similarities in components/modules.

However, 'html' files and views seem to be little bit different, which I am okay with developing similar ones if I must need to do.

1. Is there a way which I can easily re-use existing components in my Angular 4 components in Ionic app? Can I assume that if components that I wrote for Angular 4 works in Angular 4, should those components be also compatible with Ionic?
2. If I can re-use the components, would it be possible to maintain Angular 4 app and Ionic 3 app in the same code base? (e.g. I don't want to copy components to a separate Ionic project and have to maintain of 2 copies the same component in different 2 different locations.)

I would love to see example codebase that is compatible with Angular 4 & Ionic 3, but have not found one yet. I am not sure if that is doable... but `angular.io` website has the following words in the front page.

> One framework. Mobile & desktop

Comment: Consider if you really want or need Ionic. Your app will run just fine with Cordova as it stands.

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks for that info. Didn't know about Cordova... It looks like things might be much much simpler.

Comment: Ionic sits on top of Cordova, and adds native interfaces. However, applications can be built directly with Cordova, and many are.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to switch one of my apps from Angular 2 to Ionic 2 before, and it was really simple.

You can't do any magic trick to make the switch, but it's possible.

All you have to do is copy pasting + few modifications for each component/module.

**Some things you might consider when switching:**

1. You should use the Ionic UI components in order to benefit from the cross-platofrm UI. e.g `<button ion-button>`, `<ion-select>`, etc..
2. You should rewrite your app routes to work with Ionic Nav. It's really quick since you don't have to declare all your routes, and you can simply navigate by `navCtrl.push('MyPageName')`. No import needed!
3. In Ionic 3 each page/component is a module, so you will have to wrap your modules/components with [@IonicPage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/)
4. Once you are familiar with Ionic 3, create a new app, create your components using the Ionic CLI then start copy pasting and modifying each component logic and template to fit Ionic 3 as described above.

Not sure if I missed something but that's all what you have to do in general. I managed to convert my 50 components app to Ionic within one day.

If you are not sure you need Ionic, consider just using [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) or [phonegap](https://phonegap.com/) to wrap your app for mobile.